# Enable RemoveRange to remove by predicate on entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-expressions

In a business layer, there is a lot of repetitive code when removing relations to an entity that is being removed itself (without the benefit of a cascading delete on the database). In addition to the related entity deletion use case, a good approach could also be used to generally just reduce the code required with deleting a record by any matching predicate, such as by id or likewise.

```
// Simple example removing phone numbers from people entity
// The "personId" is an identifier passed into the method performing the deletion
var phones = _context.Phones
    .Where(m => m.PersonId == personId)
    .ToList();
if (phones.Count > 0)
    _context.Phones.RemoveRange(phones);
```

I'm posting this as a Q&A with the solution I came up with so that I can look it up later. Definitely would love to see other approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to overload the RemoveRange method on a DbSet with an expression. To make this as convenient as possible, implement this as a method extension on the DbSet entity itself so that the process is simply overloaded onto the DbSet with the actual RemoveRange method.

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveRange<TEntity>(
        this System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity> entities,
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var records = entities
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToList();
        if (records.Count > 0)
            entities.RemoveRange(records);
    }
}
```

With this extension in place, the RemoveRange can now be called similarly to a `Where`.

```
_context.Phones.RemoveRange(m => m.PersonId == personId);
```

Comment: But the effect is very different. One delete query for every record.

Comment: @bubi - Unfortunately you're correct. For whatever unfounded reason, I assumed calling EF6's `RemoveRange` actually was a bit more optimized. Under the hood according to `InternalSet` implementation of EF6 on CodePlex, it's just iterating as you said. Completely invalidates the approach - oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use SQL directly:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Phones WHERE PersonId=@pid", personId)
```

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456%28v=vs.113%29.aspx*

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension to EF that runs UPDATE and DELETE queries on multiple records on a single DML Statement

I can't remember the syntax but is similar to

```
context.Phones.Delete(p => p.PersonId == personId)
```

This LINQ statement becomes

```
DELETE FROM Phones WHERE PersonId = ?
```

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Comment: the syntax is in the link you provided: `context.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname").Delete();`

Comment: That's interesting - the extension runs by dynamically building a SQL command and sending directly against the database. It seems a good start, but non-SqlServer compatibility, relationships beyond 1 level of foreign keys, table names with spaces, and tables in schemas other than "dbo" seem like they'd break the batch runner that creates the SQL statements. - https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/ef14ba4d16d851018cbf9333cb49add6442cd43e/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Batch/SqlServerBatchRunner.cs

Comment: It does not use the query builder from the EF Provider. Some months ago I tried to make an extension method (Delete) and call the query builder to build only the where clause but I think that actually is not possible. The only thing I could do in the extension method was to retrieve the query from the provider and then change SELECT ... FROM with DELETE. I never used it (scary!!!!).